# Как выбросить ошибку при ложном значении?

Tags: rust

Есть некий код читающий бинарный файл, необходимо при попытке чтения неизвестного файла бросить исключение, или просто сделать вылет с ошибкой, т.к. я еще не совсем понимаю синтаксис языка прошу подсказать как это сделать:

```
impl Header {
    fn read(file: &mut std::fs::File) -> Header {
        file.rewind();

        let sig: String;
        let ver: u32;
        let web: String;
        let min: String;

        let mut file_reader = BufReader::new(file);
        let mut buffer = Vec::new();
        
        file_reader.read_until(0u8, &mut buffer);

        let good = {
            let valid = String::from("UnityFS");
            let res = valid == String::from_utf8(buffer).unwrap();
            if res {
                sig = valid;
            }
            res
        };

        // Нужно здесь выбросить ошибку
        assert_eq!(good, false, "Unknown file type.");

       ...

        Header {
            signature: sig,
            version: ver,
            web_version: web,
            min_version: min
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для вылета есть макрос `panic!` https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic.html

Comment: Только вот такая мелочь, как незнакомый тип файла, вообще-то не должна приводить к вылету... Некритичные ошибки должно быть возможно получить и обработать желаемым образом без всяких вылетов. Наверное вам надо соответствующую главу в растбуке прочитать https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html

Comment: Файл бинарный, и при попытке открытия неверного файла обработать ошибку невозможно т.к. нет варианта его прочитать, т.к. структура неизвестна. Кстати, если писать этот макрос, то я не могу вернуть значение, т.к. он мне пишет что значение `signature` возможно будет не инициализировано. Может есть еще что-то?

Comment: Обработать ошибку вполне возможно — например, предложить пользователю выбрать другой файл для чтения. Panic следует применять только тогда, когда дальнейшая работа программы невозможна вообще совсем никак, но в вашем случае ошибка чтения файла никак не мешает дальнейшей работе (можно попробовать прочитать какой-нибудь другой файл, например).

Comment: Касательно «структура неизвестна» непонятно о чём вы говорите

Comment: `assert_eq` и так сделает вылет с ошибкой, только условие сделано наоборот, должна быть проверка на `true`

Comment: Замечания по коду:

* `&mut File` как параметр это достаточно негибко, можно использовать обобщенный тип `impl std::io::Read`.
* Делать `rewind` на файле как сторонний эффект операции `Header::read`, возможно, не очень хороший стиль.
* Переменные не нужно предобъявлять, лучше использовать `let` непосредственно на месте, где значение производится (также нет нужды делать переменную `mut` и присваивать ей новые значения там, где просто можно сделать `let` на то же имя). Это позволит также не указывать тип в большинстве случаев.
* `assert!(good)` более компактно, чем `assert_eq!(good, true)`.

Comment: @mzabaluev возможно и так, но я перехожу с си на него, поэтому так делаю =)

Comment: @Kotomi понятно, но я комментировал для более скорого обучения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общепринятый подход к обработке ошибок в Rust — воспользоваться стандартным типом [Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html):

```rust
impl Header {
    fn read(file: &mut std::fs::File) -> Result<Self, HeaderReadError> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Для определения типа данных ошибки есть хорошие [рекомендации](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html#c-good-err) по API. Если ошибку в данном случае предполагается обрабатывать во внутреннем коде, можно воспользоваться простым типом `Error`, предлагаемым [anyhow](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/). Если это библиотека или большое приложение, стоит определить тип более детально и эргономично, например, воспользовавшись макросом derive из [thiserror](https://docs.rs/thiserror/latest/thiserror/):

```rust
#[derive(thiserror::Error, Debug)]
enum HeaderReadError {
    #[error("failed to read header from file")]
    Io(#[from] std::io::Error),
    #[error("invalid UTF-8 in file content")]
    Utf8Decode(#[from] std::string::FromUtf8Error),
    #[error("unknown file type")]
    UnknownFileType,
}
```

Стоит заметить, что эта структура не содержит никаких строк с описанием ошибки: они производятся на лету в сгенерированной процедурным макросом реализации `Display`.

Это определение также позволит вам удобно обработать все другие ошибочные ситуации, которые могут возникать в примере, но в оригинальном коде игнорируются или приводят к панике. Сгенерированные макросом преобразования `From` позволяют воспользоваться оператором `?`:

```rust
const HEADER_SIGNATURE: &str = "UnityFS";

impl Header {
    fn read(file: &mut std::fs::File) -> Result<Self, HeaderReadError> {
        file.rewind()?;

        let mut file_reader = BufReader::new(file);
        let mut buffer = Vec::new();

        file_reader.read_until(0u8, &mut buffer)?;

        let signature = String::from_utf8(buffer)?;

        // Нужно здесь выбросить ошибку
        if signature != HEADER_SIGNATURE {
            return Err(FileReadError::UnknownFileType);
        }

        Ok(Header {
            signature,
            // ...
        })
    }
}
```